# Using One decorator instead of multiple? "One to many" and "many to one"?

Tags: html, flask, decorator

I am trying to design a simple webpage as following to get the profile pics of students. My question below is just a simple example to ask my question and understand the logic.

Let's say; I have three classes named as Class_A2E, Class_F2J and Class_K2O. In a school, this can 1st year, 2nd year and 3rd year students. Each year student are divided by 5 class named as A-E [thus A,B,C,D,E] (1st year), F-J(2nd year) and K-O (3rd year). I want to show the picture of the student as png and give an a link as option to download as PDF file (which is high quailty).

As can be seen, I have a same decorator but with diffrent names to design such a webpage. What I would like to do; using the one decorator for all.

another problem: After printing the image, I want to return to the same class page to search for another student. However, it always gives the link for the 1stYear.

html files are in "templates" folder.
main.css is in "static" folder.
"static" folder contains png images in png_files and pdf images in pdf_files folder.

Here is my codes as below:

```
# run.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "7642e9aed5740e5ggca2de92ae021de5"

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/my_classes_A2E")
def my_classes_A2E():
    return render_template("my_classes_A2E.html", title= "my_classes_A2E", class_ids=[{'name':'ClassA'},{'name':'ClassB'},{'name':'ClassC'},{'name':'ClassD'},{'name':'ClassE'}])

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def get_input_and_print_imgs_A2E():
    class_id = request.form.get('class_id_select')
    student_name = request.form["student_name"]
    return render_template("print_student_profilepics.html",class_id=class_id, student_name=student_name, html_link="my_classes_A2E", html_title="1stYear")

@app.route("/my_classes_F2J")
def my_classes_F2J():
    return render_template("my_classes_F2J.html", title= "my_classes_F2J", class_ids=[{'name':'ClassF'},{'name':'ClassG'},{'name':'ClassH'},{'name':'ClassI'},{'name':'ClassJ'}])

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def get_input_and_print_imgs_F2J():
    class_id = request.form.get('class_id_select')
    student_name = request.form["student_name"]
    return render_template("print_student_profilepics.html",class_id=class_id, student_name=student_name, html_link="my_classes_F2J", html_title="2ndYear")

@app.route("/my_classes_K2O")
def my_classes_K2O():
    return render_template("my_classes_K2O.html", title= "my_classes_K2O", class_ids=[{'name':'ClassK'},{'name':'ClassL'},{'name':'ClassM'},{'name':'ClassN'},{'name':'ClassO'}])

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def get_input_and_print_imgs_K2O():
    class_id = request.form.get('class_id_select')
    student_name = request.form["student_name"]
    return render_template("print_student_profilepics.html",class_id=class_id, student_name=student_name, html_link="my_classes_K2O", html_title="3rdYear")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug= True)

## ANOTHER SOLUTION: the above code in run.py can be edited as below and it will also works fine. ###

from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "7642e9aed5740e5ggca2de92ae021de5"

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/my_classes_A2E/")
def my_classes_A2E():
    return render_template("my_classes_A2E.html", title= "my_classes_A2E", class_ids=[{'name':'ClassA'},{'name':'ClassB'},{'name':'ClassC'},{'name':'ClassD'},{'name':'ClassE'}])

@app.route("/my_classes_A2E/get_input_and_print_imgs_A2E", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def get_input_and_print_imgs_A2E():
    class_id = request.form.get('class_id_select')
    student_name = request.form["student_name"]
    return render_template("print_student_profilepics.html",class_id=class_id, student_name=student_name, html_link="my_classes_A2E", html_title="1stYear")

@app.route("/my_classes_F2J/")
def my_classes_F2J():
    return render_template("my_classes_F2J.html", title= "my_classes_F2J", class_ids=[{'name':'ClassF'},{'name':'ClassG'},{'name':'ClassH'},{'name':'ClassI'},{'name':'ClassJ'}])

@app.route("/my_classes_F2J/get_input_and_print_imgs_F2J", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def get_input_and_print_imgs_F2J():
    class_id = request.form.get('class_id_select')
    student_name = request.form["student_name"]
    return render_template("print_student_profilepics.html",class_id=class_id, student_name=student_name, html_link="my_classes_F2J", html_title="1stYear")

@app.route("/my_classes_K2O/")
def my_classes_K2O():
    return render_template("my_classes_K2O.html", title= "my_classes_K2O", class_ids=[{'name':'ClassK'},{'name':'ClassL'},{'name':'ClassM'},{'name':'ClassN'},{'name':'ClassO'}])

@app.route("/my_classes_K2O/get_input_and_print_imgs_K2O", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def get_input_and_print_imgs_K2O():
    class_id = request.form.get('class_id_select')
    student_name = request.form["student_name"]
    return render_template("print_student_profilepics.html",class_id=class_id, student_name=student_name, html_link="my_classes_K2O", html_title="1stYear")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug= True)
```

#

```
########## this is layout.html as template for all other html fies ######
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">

        {% if title %}
            <title> MY WEB PAGE - {{ title }} </title>
        {% else %}
            <title> MY WEB PAGE </title>
        {% endif %}

        <header class="site-header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <a style="color:#z00000" class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/my_classes_A2E"><b>1stYear</b></a>
                    <a style="color:#z00000" class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/my_classes_F2J"><b>2ndYear</b></a>
                    <a style="color:#z00000" class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/my_classes_K2O"><b>3rdYear</b></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>               
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>

################ my_classes_A2E.html #######################
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1 style="color:#f00000"> This page is under construction and will be updated soon! </h1>
    <form style="width: 50px !important; min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px;" name="pass_class_idt" id="pass_class_id" action="." method="POST">
        <label>Class ID 1stYear </label>
        <select name="class_id_select" class="selectpicker form-control">
          {% for class_id in class_ids %}
            <option value="{{ class_id.name }}">{{ class_id.name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <label> Student Name in1stYear :</label>
        <input type="text" name="student_name">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}

################ my_classes_F2J.html #######################
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1 style="color:#f00000"> This page is under construction and will be updated soon! </h1>
    <form style="width: 50px !important; min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px;" name="pass_class_id" id="pass_class_id" action="." method="POST">
        <label>Class ID 2ndYear </label>
        <select name="class_id_select" class="selectpicker form-control">
          {% for class_id in class_ids %}
            <option value="{{ class_id.name }}">{{ class_id.name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <label> Student Name in 2ndYear:</label>
        <input type="text" name="student_name">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}

################ my_classes_K2O.html #######################
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1 style="color:#f00000"> This page is under construction and will be updated soon! </h1>
    <form style="width: 50px !important; min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px;" name="pass_class_id" id="pass_class_id" action="." method="POST">
        <label> Class ID 3rdYear </label>
        <select name="class_id_select" class="selectpicker form-control">
          {% for class_id in class_ids %}
            <option value="{{ class_id.name }}">{{ class_id.name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <label> Student Name in 3rdYear:</label>
        <input type="text" name="student_name">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}


################ print_student_profilepics.html #######################

{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1 style="color:#f00000"> This page is under construction and will be updated soon! </h1>
    <div class="container"> 
        <embed src="/static/png_files/{{ class_id }}_{{ student_name }}_profilepics.png" width = "700" height= "700">
    </div>  
    <p style="margin-left:23rem;"> <b> Download as: <a href="/static/pdf_files/{{ class_id }}_{{ student_name }}_profilepics.pdf" class="button"> PDF </b></a> <small style="color:#f00000;"> (for High Quality) </small> </p>
    <p style="margin-left:23rem;"> <b> Go Back To     : <a  href="{{ html_link }}"> {{ html_title }} </b></a> </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: here is the zip file of the code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8cx73vfi02ajp0/my_class_web.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Parametrizing routes

When defining a flask route the `< >` syntax enables you to define a variable url string parameter, that will take care of all routes written in that form:

For instance:

```py
@app.route("/my-classes/<class_group>")
def my_classes(class_group):
    ...
```

Would route urls like `/my-classes/A2E` through the `my_classes(class_group)` function with the `class_group` parameter set to str: "A2E". I have updated from your actual initial url pattern, `/my_classes_A2E` because it is a more standard way of routing, although you could achieve the same effect with `/my_classes_<class_group>`, if you want to keep yours. Also, it's more conventional to write routes with hyphens `-` instead of underscores `_` (see the url of that stackoverflow link !)

#### Routes priority

> another problem: After printing the image, I want to return to the same class page to search for another student. However, it always gives the link for the 1stYear.

Regarding this remark note that you had defined the same url routes for your 3 class groups !

```
@app.route("/", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def get_input_and_print_imgs_A2E():
    ...
@app.route("/", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def get_input_and_print_imgs_F2J():
    ...
@app.route("/", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def get_input_and_print_imgs_K2O():
    ...
```

Though flask doesn't raise any error when you launch the server, only the first function will treat your `/` url request, which explains why you would only get the 1stYear links.

#### Wrapping it up

You might be interesting in first defining the dictionary that will hold the logic of your classes: these are the first 3 dictionaries. Given this you can reduce your 2*3 routes to 2 routes because all the "group" logic would be factorized.

```py
# run.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "7642e9aed5740e5ggca2de92ae021de5"

class_group_dict = {
    "A2E": [{'name': 'ClassA'}, {'name': 'ClassB'}, {'name': 'ClassC'}, {'name': 'ClassD'}, {'name': 'ClassE'}],
    "F2J": [{'name': 'ClassF'}, {'name': 'ClassG'}, {'name': 'ClassH'}, {'name': 'ClassI'}, {'name': 'ClassJ'}],
    "K2O": [{'name': 'ClassK'}, {'name': 'ClassL'}, {'name': 'ClassM'}, {'name': 'ClassN'}, {'name': 'ClassO'}]
}

class_group_to_year = {
    "A2E": "1stYear",
    "F2J": "2ndYear",
    "K2O": "3rdYear"
}

class_id_to_class_year = {
    class_dict["name"]: class_year for class_year, list_class in class_group_dict.items()
    for class_dict in list_class
}

@app.route("/my-classes/<class_group>/get-input-and-print-imgs", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_input_and_print_imgs(class_group):  # test
    class_id = request.form.get('class_id_select')
    student_name = request.form["student_name"]
    return render_template("print_student_profilepics.html",
                           class_id=class_id, student_name=student_name,
                           html_link=f"my_classes_{class_id_to_class_year[class_group]}",
                           html_title=class_group_to_year[class_group])


@app.route("/my-classes/<class_group>")
def my_classes(class_group):  # class_group: one of ["A2E", "F2J",  "K2O"]
    return render_template(f"my_classes_{class_group}.html",
                           title=f"my_classes_{class_group}",
                           class_ids=class_group_dict[class_group])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#### Final notes

I haven't taken the liberty of changing the .html names but conventions would suggest using hyphens instead. Also for clarity, maybe it be better to decide for one naming field for the `class_name` / `id` (ie. classA, classB, ect...) since it is referred with both.

#### HTML files update

You need to change the action field of the `<form>` tag in `my_classes_A2E`, `my_classes_F2J`, `my_classes_K2O`, to point to the good route, ie. this would be for `my_classes_A2E`

```html
<form style="width: 50px !important; min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px;" name="pass_class_idt" id="pass_class_id" action="/my-classes/A2E/get-input-and-print-imgs" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will go through to understand the route you have written. This is a bit complicated form me to understand. I have sent the files in dropbox link (https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8cx73vfi02ajp0/my_class_web.zip?dl=0). Is it possible if you test and send me the final codes. I tried and updated but it did not work for me (404 not found error.)

Comment: f"my_classes_{class_id_to_class_year[class_group]}"; if class_group is one A2E,F2J or K2O, there will be an error.

Comment: Indeed it should be `f"my_classes_{class_group}"` sorry it's an error on my side

Comment: Hi @eddiemalou: how do you pass class_group values to the app.routes? Is it possible for you to update my codes in the dropbox link (https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8cx73vfi02ajp0/my_class_web.zip?dl=0) with yours? Thanks.

Comment: Hi have updated my answer to include the HTML update that you should make for  `my_classes_A2E.html`, `my_classes_F2J.html`, `my_classes_K2O.html` so that the action effectively routes your form correctly. Let me know if this works now.

Comment: What I have changed: I directly copied your python script into run.py file. Then, change the <form> tag in my_classes_A2E, F2J and K2O html files. Here is the final code: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/r73h24c4ggz3gwx/my_class_web_v1.zip?dl=0). "Not Found" error. Do I have to update anything else? Thanks.

Comment: After launching your flask server, what is the html address your are using ? It should be one of:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/my-classes/A2E`

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/my-classes/F2J`

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/my-classes/K2O`. Indeed 

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/my_classes_A2E` , ect, don't route to anything anymore with the current run.py

Comment: Thank you very very much. It was a great help.